# Apigee: Set use.proxy dynamically instead of hard-coded

Tags: service, proxy, apigee, callout

We need to clarify if the use.proxy is true or false and this value should come dynamically via the properties file. Following two scenarios can happen:

- If we send a request or a service callout to the real backend, we need use.proxy=true.
- If we send a request or a service callout to the simulated backend (for continuous integration), we need use.proxy=false.

Unfortunately the simulation is an IP, which is not accessible via a proxy.

What we tried out:

```
<Property name="use.proxy">{_PROXY_CHOICE}</Property>
```

And in the properties-file the argument:

```
context.setVariable('_PROXY_CHOICE', '${proxy.choice}');
```

But nothing happened. Anyone any clues how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would have proxy to real backend configured in the properties file and have use.proxy set to true - so by default it keeps using real backend. And use.proxy to false in case of simulation in the proxy - so just play around with use.proxy based on the request - as i understand you can change this per request in proxy.